# SELECT Query where only one of three fields containing Foreign Keys is filled

Tags: ms-access, iif

As shown below the Table `Recording` contains three foreign keys, only one of which will be filled for any one entry. My question is how can I format a select statement in Access that will only pull the names from the relevant table given the foreign key for that table?

I have tried using IIf, which works when checking which Foreign Key is Not Null after the SELECT:

```
SELECT Recording.[idRecording],
       IIf(Recording.[Artist_idArtist] Is Not Null,  
             Artist.[artName] , 
                 IIf(Recording.[Band_idBand] is Not Null, 
                      Band.[bName], 
                        Composer.[cName]))
FROM ...
```

But putting any conditions after the FROM statement, to get the correct JOIN, results in an error:

```
FROM 
   IIf(Recording.[Artist_idArtist] Is Not Null, 
         Artist INNER JOIN Recording ON Recording.[Artist_idArtist] = Artist.[idArtist],
            IIf(Recording.Band_idBand Is Not Null,
                  Band INNER JOIN Recording ON Recording.[Band_idBand] = Band.[idBand],
                    Composer INNER JOIN Recording ON Recording.[Composer_idComposer] = Composer.[idComposer]));
```

I'm new to this so I'm probably missing something obvious, or going about it the wrong way. I believe what I've ended up with here is an Exclusive Arc? I'm not sure if this is even a good design, I had thought of scrapping the Recording table and simply adding the foreign keys to Track.

For reference here is the Relationship Design:

[image: ER]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the problem with LEFT JOINs

```
SELECT
    R.idRecording,
    Nz(A.artName, Nz(B.bName, C.cName))
FROM
    ((Recording R
    LEFT JOIN Artist A
        ON R.Artist_idArtist = A.idArtist)
    LEFT JOIN Band B
        ON R.Band_idBand = B.idBand)
    LEFT JOIN Composer C
        ON R.Composer_idComposer = C.idComposer
```

They return all the records form the table on the left side and only the records from the table on the right side for which the join condition is met.

I also simplified the `IIf` cascade with the `Nz` function, which returns the second argument when the first one is `null`.

I also use short aliases for table names, thus simplifying the query further.